# Python regex search (frustrated with regex)

Tags: python, regex

I have the below string of text;
 
I need to parse/print out the line "**jil < fwks_future_dated_change_batch.jil | tee SCR232425.log**" (second line from the bottom).
Basically "^jil <....$" (beginning of line, followed by 'jil <' followed by anything, then end of line)
I've been fiddling around with re.match and re.search but have been unable to assemble the required regex.

```
Servers for deployment:
For BT Test:
MER1-BATCHT3
MER1-BATCHT4

For BT Pre-Prod:
MER2-BATCHP03
MER2-BATCHP04

AUTOSYS Instructions:

Get the files from PVCS
a.k.a. \\scm-share\scm\pvcs\VM\Projects\Batch_Apps\Batch_Apps\AutoSys\FutureDatedChangeBatch\

fwks_future_dated_change_batch-TEST.jil
fwks_future_dated_change_batch-PROD.jil

For TEST Autosys
Log onto the Test AUTOSYS unix machine
Run the command
. /opt/CA/autosys451/autouser/autosys.ksh*

FTP fwks_future_dated_change_batch-TEST.jil onto TEST autosys

Rename fwks_future_dated_change_batch-TEST.jil to fwks_future_dated_change_batch.jil

Run the commands

jil < fwks_future_dated_change_batch.jil | tee SCR232425.log
Check for message Exit Code = 0 at the end
```

Comment: So what is your regex, and what output does it give you? I find e.g. http://regex101.com useful for developing and testing regular expressions

Comment: I think `"(?im)^(jil < .*?)$"` does what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
match = re.search("(?m)^jil[^\n]+?jil.*?$", subject, re.IGNORECASE)
if match:
    result = match.group()
else:
    result = ""
```

Comment: @radamund Did this solve your problem? Hey btw, I notice that you haven't yet voted on StackOverflow. If this answer or another answer solves your problem, please consider "accepting it" by clicking the checkmark on the left, as this is how the reputation system works (accepting an anwer gives reputation to both the answerer and to you). Of course there is no obligation to do so. Later when you have more reputation you can also upvote questions. Thanks for listening to my 20-second SO rep tutorial. :)